# Compare two variables rows and delete the duplicates in same table in vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a table that holds jobs for a jobs basket. If you are not logged in as a user then your jobs get a sessionid from a cookie.

If you log in after and you already have jobs in your signed out basket and your signed in basket to add them together with your id and set the session_id to 0.

The table looks like this:

```
vacancy_id  |  user_id  |  session_id

  10            1            0

  10            0            1636252

  4             0            1636252
```

So when I run the SQL the vacancy with id 10 and a session id will be deleted and the vacancy with id 4 and session id will have a session id 0 and a user_id of 1.

I did try this below but I got an error saying

> "You can't specify target table 'v1' for update in FROM clause"

code:

```
            Dim current_sessionid As String = GetCookie("job_session_id")
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(current_sessionid) Then
            Else

                Dim oConn3 As New MySqlConnection(DSN)
                Dim oCmd3 As New MySqlCommand
                Dim oRS3 As MySqlDataReader = Nothing

                Dim oConn4 As New MySqlConnection(DSN)
                Dim oCmd4 As New MySqlCommand
                Dim oRS4 As MySqlDataReader = Nothing

                Try

                    oConn3.Open()

                    oCmd3.Connection = oConn

                    oCmd3.CommandText = "UPDATE vacancies_basket AS v1 SET v1.user_id = @user_id, v1.session_id = '0' WHERE session_id = @currentsession AND " _
                    & "(SELECT v2.vacancy_id FROM vacancies_basket AS v2 WHERE user_id = @user_id) <> v1.vacancy_id"
                    oCmd3.Prepare()
                    oCmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_id", User.User_ID)
                    oCmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@currentsession", GetCookie("job_session_id"))
                    oCmd3.ExecuteNonQuery()

                    oConn3.Close()
                    oConn3.Dispose()
                    oCmd3.Dispose()
                    oRS3 = Nothing

                    oCmd4.CommandText = "DELETE FROM vacancies_basket WHERE session_id=@currentsession"
                    oCmd4.Prepare()
                    oCmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@currentsession", GetCookie("job_session_id"))
                    oCmd4.ExecuteNonQuery()

                Catch ex As Exception
                    SendAlertEMail("App_Code/functions.vb/LogUserId()/jobbasket", ex)
                Finally
                    oConn4.Close()
                    oConn4.Dispose()
                    oCmd4.Dispose()
                    oRS4 = Nothing
                End Try
            End If
```

Comment: Why was this given a downvote?

Comment: My Guess: "too localized"
This question is unlikely to help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet. For help making this question more broadly applicable, see the FAQ.

Comment: it is help for others if they need a way to access one table, compare two rows and delete the duplicates. i have made it more towards what i am doing but that is the reason for the question... so please help